# Bitbucket Api to get commits in a branch

Tags: git, rest, bitbucket

I am currently automating sending release emails to our customers and would like to be able to fetch all the commit details (comments + hash + person) and put that in the release mail.

Any idea how to do that?

Cheers
Kris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command will bring the commit-id, the author and the commit message for all commits from TAG1 to TAG2:

```
curl -s --user USER:PASS --request GET https://BITBUCKET-SERVER/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT/repos/REPO/commits?since=TAG1\&until=TAG2 | jq --raw-output '.values[] | .displayId + "\n" + .author.name + "\n" + .message + "\n\n==========\n"'
```

Comment: Marcelo How to get the latest commit of specific branch ?

Comment: `https://BITBUCKET-SERVER/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT/repos/REPO/branches?filterText={part of the name of the branch}`

In the response you will find the latest commit hash